# Can't use routes in Express.JS with nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

So I set up nginx in front of Express.JS and all is good, the issue is that say I go to `website.com/users`, I end up getting a `404 Not Found`. Apparently going to `website.com` is fine, but I guess It's not passing through to routes. Here's my config file for nginx

```
upstream default {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name website.com default;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/default.log;

    return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://default/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

My users route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It seems like a problem with your router. 
Can you edit the question and add the router that is handling **/users**

Comment: All set, just edited it @SwarajGiri

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your route to look like this:

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

You might also need to include the port for the express server (3000 is default):

```
proxy_pass http://default:3000;
```